# How to get the raster() function in R to round to the outside of a specified extent?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

How can I get the `raster()` function to round to the *outside* of the specified x/y min/max? For example, what I see:

```
> raster(xmn = 0, xmx = 1.01,
+        ymn = 0, ymx = 1.01,
+        res = 1)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0.01, 1.01  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

and what I want to see:

```
> raster(xmn = 0, xmx = 1.01,
+        ymn = 0, ymx = 1.01,
+        res = 1)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2, 2, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 2, 0, 2  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

or anything that includes the specified xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax *within* the resulting raster object. I realize this is an easy example but I'm looking for general code that can be used for many different values of xmn, xmx, ymn, ymx, and res.

Thanks in advance! (:

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this exactly answers your question, what you need may depend a bit on your actual workflow, but it seems that what you are looking for is `floor(extent)`.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(xmn = 0, xmx = 1.01, ymn = 0, ymx = 1.01)
e <- floor(extent(r))
rr <- raster(e, res=1, crs=crs(r))
rr

#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 2, 2, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 2, 0, 2  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Note that the `floor` method for `Extent` objects rounds *min* x and y **down**, but rounds *max* x and y **up**. There is also a `ceiling` method that does the opposite, and a `round` method that goes to the nearest integer.

In other cases (depending if there is data you want to keep, and whether the resolution needs to change or not) you may want one of these

```
x <- extend(r, e)
y <- setExtent(r, e)
extent(r) <- e
```

If you need to align an extent with a Raster*, you can do

```
alignExtent(e, r, snap='near')
```

You can also do things like

```
e <- round(e + 15)
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks so much! Unfortunately res isn't actually 1 in my case. Do you know of a function that does the same thing as floor(extent(r)) but rounds to the closest 15, for example?

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks!! I think `e <- floor(extent(r)/res)*res` and then `rr <- raster(e, res = res)` ends up doing what I need.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is how you could "round out" to another number than 1